# Can't pass data from home to results_page by Navigator.push() method

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a problem with this flutter app, and I cant find the solution as there is no error. what happens is when it navigates from home to the result page, the calculations doesn't happen or the values are not sent I don't understand what's happening here. Any help is much appreciated. here is the link to the git repo https://github.com/TauqeerAli/bmi-calculator-flutter2

Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ResultsPage(
                        bmiResult: calc.calculateBMI(),
                        resultText: calc.getResult(),
                        interpretation: calc.getInterpretation(),
                      ),

There are no error messages. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the repo ,The calculation indeed happens but gives the wrong answer

in `calculator_brain.dart` you need to replace the method

```
 String calculateBMI() {
    _bmi = weight / pow(height, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }
```

with

```
 String calculateBMI() {
    _bmi = weight / pow(height/100, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }
```

to get the right answer. as the formula takes `height` in meters not in centimeters.